# WiX Heat.exe Win64 Components - Win64="yes"

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm building an installer at the moment that targets just 64bit machines.  Part of the process involves running `Heat.exe` to produce a `Fragment` elements containing part of the deployed application.

The problem is the components that are produced by heat produce ICE:80 errors which is WiX complaining that the components target 32bit systems and my installer is trying to load these into:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
```

Looking at the documentation there is a `-platform` switch that can be used to tell `Heat` that we are targeting an x64 environment however there is no clue in the documentation on how to use this switch.  I've tried:

```
-platform=x64

-platform=Win64
```

Nothing seems to effect the output in order to set the `Win64` attribute on the generated components.  Has anyone figured this out?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

If I manually edit the harvested components to add `Win64="yes"` the ICE error goes away.

In my `<Product>` element I have `Platform="x64"` as I understand it `candle` should take this and work out that the components should be set to x64 by default but this isn't working it seems.

Very confused.

Comment: I've gotten this working for now by using the InstallerPlatform property in the `.wixproj` file.  This is the same as setting the `-arch` switch on the command line.

Comment: What I do normally for such cases: use an XSLT-file on the heat-commandline that will add the `Win64='yes'`-attribute to each component. Even then I always use the `arch`-parameter and the `platform`-property, just to be sure. If you need an appropriate XSLT-file, I will post it in an answer (as a comment is too short).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here would be the XSLT-file. Save it as e.g. `HeatTransform.xslt`:

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  exclude-result-prefixes="wix">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="wix:Wix">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- The following enters the directive for adding the config.wxi include file to the dynamically generated file -->
      <!--xsl:processing-instruction name="include">$(sys.CURRENTDIR)wix\config.wxi</xsl:processing-instruction-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ### Adding the Win64-attribute to all Components -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <!-- Adding the Win64-attribute as we have a x64 application -->
        <xsl:attribute name="Win64">yes</xsl:attribute>

        <!-- Now take the rest of the inner tag -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, in your `heat`-commandline add the parameter `-t <PathToYourFile>\HeatTransform.xslt`. This will add the `Win64`-attribute to every component.
Additionally I have `Platform='x64'`-attribute in my WiX source file(s) and add the `-arch x64`-parameter to the invocation of `candle`, as you already described in your question.

Comment: The only solution works for me!

Answer (score 23):

I also had this problem.
Below is what I've done and it helped.

1)

Open **.wixproj** file in notepad and manually change Condition-s in PropertyGroup-s to be "**x64**" instead of "x86":

> ```
> <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform>
> ...
> <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
> ...
> <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' ">
> ...
> ```

2)

Go to Configuration Manager for the solution and make sure that **x64** is chosen as the platform for the Wix project.

Although **Heat** still generates Component nodes without Win64="yes", but it builds ok and installs to the C:\Program Files!

Comment: It seems to me that `InstallerPlatform` should be used in favor of `Platform`.

Comment: FWIW, your not changing the condition  (It's still Platform is null) your changing the assigned value.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation of the [Package Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html) and [candle task](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/candle.html) suggests to use the `InstallerPlatform` property:

> **Platform**
>
> The platform supported by the package. Use of this attribute is discouraged; 
>   instead, specify the -arch switch at the candle.exe command line or the 
>   InstallerPlatform property in a .wixproj MSBuild project.

> **InstallerPlatform**
>
> Specifies the processor architecture for the package. [...] This is 
>   equivalent to the -arch switch in candle.exe.

that is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <InstallerPlatform>x64</InstallerPlatform>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And for completness: If you want a single WiX-Project for multiple target platforms you should have a look at [Platform identification in WiX 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1860161/1671066).

Comment: Thanks, simply adding these 3 lines worked for me (`<PropertyGroup> <Installer...`)

Comment: I did this and I see an -arch switch appear in the output, but it still did not work.  -arch x86 still writes to the System 64 folder, not System32 :(

Comment: Which file is this in?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio:

1. Select Project Properties
2. Select "Tool Settings" tab
3. In "Additional parameters (compiler)" type: -arch x64